# Affect or Effect?

Tags: word-choice, differences

I still don't really know, despite trying to read the definitions.

I believe this sentence is correct but let me know.

> I seriously wish I could foresee the future and know of all the
>   different factors that could **effect** the stock. I want to go all in but
>   I'm scared.

Is it **affect** or **effect**?

Comment: You want 'affect' in that sentence.

Comment: Generally speaking (there are tricky cases) you want "effect" when describing the result of an action and "affect" when describing the action itself.  In this case the "different factors" are the action which is affecting the stock, eventually producing an effect (eg, change in stock price) as a result.

Answer (score 3):

That would mean that you wish you knew what *caused* the stock. The word you're looking for is affect, you wish you knew what caused variance, or vicissitudes in the stock market, am I right?

[Affect](https://www.google.com/search?q=affect&rlz=1C1GGGE___US550US551&oq=affect&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4929j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) (verb): "have an effect on; make a difference to."

[Effect](https://www.google.com/search?q=affect&rlz=1C1GGGE___US550US551&oq=affect&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4929j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=effect%20define) (verb): "cause (something) to happen; bring about."

"I am greatly distraught inasmuch as I can't foresee the many greatly varying factors that together make an impact (or difference) on the fluctuations of the stock market."

See [this page](http://dictionary.reference.com/help/faq/language/d70.html) for a more in-depth comparison of the two.

Answer (score 0):

You effect a change.  Here the word effect precedes an impacting result.  You caused change.

A change affects you. The word affect precedes a subject that was impacted. A change changed you.

Both affect and effect are about impact.  The subtle difference is that one is for the impact itself.  The other is about the thing impacted.

Lets mix them up:

If you say you affect a change then you're saying you changed a change.
If you say a change effects you then you're saying a change caused you to be.

Mnemonic: your parents got together one day and **e**ffected you.  Later, when you learned how that works, you went, **EEEEE**W!